# TodoItems do not appear in UI using React and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I'm following Traversey Media's React [crash course,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBws8MSXN7A) and I wanted to extend what he built to save TodoItems to a Firebase realtime database. The TodoItems save just fine, but do not appear in the UI.

I've tried having the app start with a hard-coded TodoItem in case it was an issue of having an empty array, but this does not help anything.

relevant methods:

(full code available at https://github.com/etothepi16/react-todo)

```
// Delete todo item
  delTodo = (id) => {
    fire.database().ref(`todos/${id}`).remove()
      .then(function(){
        this.setState({
          // Loop through todos array and filter out item with provided ID
          // ... is the spread operator, used here to copy the todos array
                    todos: [...this.state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id)]
        })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message);
      })
    });
  };

  // Add todo
  addTodo = (title) => {
    let id = uuid.v4();
    let database = fire.database();
    let todosRef = database.ref(`todos/${id}`);
    let newTodo = {
      id: this.id,
      title: title,
      completed: false
    }
    todosRef.set(newTodo).then(
      this.setState({todos: [...this.state.todos, newTodo]})
    );
  };

  render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className='App'>
                    <div className='container'>
                        <Header />
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path='/'
                            render={(props) => (
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    <AddTodo addTodo={this.addTodo} />
                                    <Todos
                                        todos={this.state.todos}
                                        markComplete={this.markComplete}
                                        delTodo={this.delTodo}
                                    />
                                </React.Fragment>
                            )}
                        />
                        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
};
```

```
class Todos extends Component {
  render(){
    return this.props.todos.map((todo)=>(
        <TodoItem todo={todo} markComplete={this.props.markComplete} delTodo={this.props.delTodo}/>  
    ));
  }
}
```

TodoItem.js

```
render() {
        const { id, title } = this.props.todo;
        return (
            <div style={this.getStyle()}>
                <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.props.markComplete.bind(this, id)} />{' '}
                    { title }
                    <button className="delete" style={btnStyle} onClick={this.props.delTodo.bind(this,id)}>x</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

No TodoItems show up in the UI as stated before.

Error message:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `todos` is marked as required in `TodoItem`, but its value is `undefined`.
>      in TodoItem (at Todos.js:8)
>      in Todos (at App.js:87)
>      in Route (at App.js:81)
>      in div (at App.js:79)
>      in div (at App.js:78)
>      in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>      in BrowserRouter (at App.js:77)
>      in App (at src/index.js:4)

Error I get when I try to add a new TodoItem:
[AddTodo error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z5y0.png)

> Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'todos.7cda085d-7653-4895-a140-d6f2629af9ca.id'
>
> C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/react-todo/src/App.js:70
>
> ```
>   67 |     title: title,
>   68 |     completed: false
>   69 |   }
> > 70 |   todosRef.set(newTodo).then(
> ^ 71 |     this.setState({todos: [...this.state.todos, newTodo]})
>   72 |   );
>   73 | };
>
> 262 | 
> 263 | this.onSubmit = e => {
> 264 |   e.preventDefault();
> > 265 |   this.props.addTodo(this.state.title);         
> 266 |   this.setState({
> 267 |     title: ''
> 268 |   });
> ```

Comment: Post `TodoItem` component.

Comment: @ravibagul91 done, thanks!

Comment: Hi Paul, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onClick={this.props.delTodo.bind(this,id)}
```

You don't need to bind `this` here.

You just need to create an anonymous function and call your `markComplete` and `delTodo` function with given `id` in that anonymous function,

```
    render() {
        const { id, title } = this.props.todo;
        return (
            <div style={this.getStyle()}>
                <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => this.props.markComplete(id)} />{' '}
                    { title }
                    <button className="delete" style={btnStyle} onClick={() => this.props.delTodo(id)}>x</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I found part of the problem... I had a stray `this.` in App.js. But after implementing your changes, I can add todo items, but they do not load up on page load.

Comment: It means when you load `Todos` component `this.state.todos` is empty.

Comment: As you have separate `About` component, same way you can have `Todos` component separately and move all the logic in that component.

Comment: I already have a Todos component, what are you suggesting I should move into there?

Comment: I mean to say, just have Route like `<Route exact path='/' component={TodoComponent} />` create separte `TodoComponent` file and move your `add`, `delete` and data fetching logic into that component.

Comment: Interesting, I’ll try this